# What kind of ram usage is bad ram usage?

Tags: debian, monitoring, memory

We have been monitoring our Debian servers' ram usage in order to receive alerts when the ram usage goes over a certain % threshold.

However, a high % ram usage is not necessarily a problem can even be desirable as it suggests the ram is doing it's job caching things and speeding things up (there are plenty of serverfault questions about that).  The result is that I'm not so sure we can definitively say "< 30% ram available is a bad thing" and I mean bad in the sense of - send somebody  a text message and wake them up.

We can account for things like disk cache when calculating the available ram but the same problem still applies - sometimes we *want* lots of ram to be used.  Alternatively we can monitor things like swapio to identify high levels of swapping but again, this is not necessarily of itself a bad thing.  It could indicate a *busy* server, not a failing one.

Can anybody suggest any ram metric we can measure and definitively state "this much of that is a problem that somebody needs to go look at"?  It might be as simple as saying "no server should ever have less than 10% free".

Alternatively, are we barking up the wrong tree?  Should we just monitor the services themselves (e.g. are pages loading quickly) and then keep the ram level logged and graphed in case we ever need to look at it?

Comment: When available - buffers - cached is low, then you are in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should consider monitoring swap usage. When Linux starts swapping aggressively it means something is eating up the memory for some reason.